# confused with facebook json object with jquery and nodejs

Tags: facebook, json, node.js, express

writing my first facebook/node/express app

With express I'm using

```
 app.post('/friends', function(req, res) {
        graph.get("/me/friends?fields=id,name", function(err, res2) {
         res.send(res2);
     });
 });
```

client side I'm using

```
 $('#getFriends').click(function() {
      $.post('/friends', function(data) {
           console.log(data);
           console.log(data.length);
      });
 });
```

With a previous app, I called the graph from the client side with getJSON and looped through everything with a for loop to print out the id and name. With this, I'm confused. Do I need to convert it to an array or a string first? Am I using the express request properly?
It logs the data object, but even when I go to print the length it's null.

Comment: I do notice that you're posting to '/friends', however your route is set up at '/friendsphotos'. Not sure if this is your entire issue but that may be a good first step

Comment: thanks. bad copy and paste. :)

I figured it out, changed the express to use app.all instead of app.post and changed the jQuery to use getJSON.

Would still like to know what to do with this implementation though with respect to json objects

Comment: Using app.all is probably not a good idea, as it will match any HTTP method type. You should probably limit it to the methods which you are planning to use. If you are unsure of which type of request your server is receiving, you can figure it out my logging the incoming request and taking a look. Since you switch to use getJSON, I assume you are now using a get request, and should probably use app.get in your route.

Comment: changing it to get from post worked.